# What should I do after my iphone 6 froze and turned into black screen with a small loading loading sign?

Tags: iphone

My iphone 6 froze and turned into black screen with a small loading loading sign.
I charged it last night for the whole night and woke up and found out nothing happened.

Comment: Try holding the home button and the power button simultaneously for about 10 seconds. Connect it to a computer running iTunes if that should not work.

Comment: My iPhone had a similar Black Screen of Death last week. I knew about Home/Power and tried that without success for 24-36 hours. Finally, I found another option: Power Button and the Volume Down button. 

Apparently, the former is a Hard Reset and the latter is a Soft Reset?

Comment: This is only true for the iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus.